# Is it possible to get font family of particular text in PDF with PDF-XChange Editor?

Tags: pdf, font-identification

I have [this PDF](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/2041-210X.14097) and want to **select a particular text and find out what font it is in**. Is it possible in PDF-XChange Editor, or Foxit PDF reader? I have tried to look up different advices on Internet like [this one](https://superuser.com/a/585485/93604) but they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested method in the linked web page is shortly "select a text with the text selection tool". That's the same what's needed if you are going to copy some text from a PDF to another application like Windows Notepad, MS Word etc...

Then check the font name, size and variant from the properties panel. Properties panel should be opened at first. It works with free and paid versions of PDF-XChange. I tested in version 10.0.

[image]

**There's one trap:** If the selected piece of text  happens to contain more than one font, the properties panel displays "various". It will be "various" even in case the fonts look the same, for ex. Lato Regular True Type and Lato Regular Type 1. Both of them can exist in the same line. In addition there's some spaces which are of different font than the visible text around the empty space. Select only one letter to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! Works in Version 10, didn't work in version 9 (added a screenshot to your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "click" aspect.....

... There's **no need** for any tools beyond **Adobe Acrobat** or **Adobe Reader** to see what fonts are used in a PDF.

- Open the PDF in **Acrobat** or **Reader**
- Choose `File > Properties`
- Click the `Fonts` tab across the top of the **Document Properties** window...

[image]
[image]
<sub>(These screenshots are from your linked PDF.)</sub>

Adobe Reader is free. So even if your other tools *can't* list the fonts, it wouldn't cost anything to download Reader for this purpose.

---

I *am* using a *legacy version* of Acrobat. If, by chance, the Properties menu item has moved in more recent versions of the apps... I *encourage* anyone to edit this answer in order to update the item location.

Comment: I hate Adobe Acrobat. I replaced it with Foxit because of how annoying the free version was and how they were unfair when I paid the pro version. Do I really need Adobe for this?

Comment: Anyway, I didn't ask for list of all fonts... I am interested in the font family of **particular text**.

Comment: Okay well, I won't EVER argue with "I hate Adobe". But it is common users have at least Reader. I can't comment on any other tools. As far as I know.. I've never seen anything that is "target aware" for identifying fonts in a PDF. Of course, you *could* open the PDF in Inkscape or Illustrator and the type *may* be "live". Since Acrobat is showing embedded fonts, there's a high probability a vector app will open and read the fonts. In which case,.. click and the font panel will show the font. But this is commonly a 1-page-at-a-time thing.